# Plot the percentage of persons for whom a certain value is exceeded

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, bar-chart, percentage

I would like to plot the proportion of users, that exceeded a certain value for a variable.

Example data:

```
game_data <- data.frame(player = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), day= c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3), n_wins = c(0,2,1,1,0,0,2,0,1))

game_data
  player day n_wins
1      1   1      0
2      1   2      2
3      1   3      1
4      2   1      1
5      2   2      0
6      2   3      0
7      3   1      2
8      3   2      0
9      3   3      1
```

I unfortunately have no idea how to plot this, this is just the basic code:

```
game_data %>% group_by(player) %>% summarize(allwins = sum(n_wins)) %>% ggplot(aes(x=?, y = ?)) + geom_bar()
```

I want to plot the proportion of users in percentage (y-axis) that had in total 1 vs. 2 vs. 3 wins (so a 33,3% bar for 1, a 0% bar for 2 and a 66,7% bar for 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, here is one that pre-calculates the values and goes with `identity` as `stat`:

```
library(tidyverse)

game_data %>% 
  group_by(player) %>% 
  summarize(allwins = sum(n_wins)) %>% 
  add_count(allwins) %>%
  complete(allwins = 1:max(allwins), 
           fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
  distinct(allwins, Percentage = round(n / length(na.omit(player)) * 100, 2)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = allwins, y = Percentage)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

Output:

[image]